# Clearing Input after submit With react hooks

Tags: reactjs

How do I clear the input after button submit? The text I input is still there after I submit.

Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciated. Thanks again

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("");

 const handleInput = e => {
        setValue(e.target.value);
      };

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setValue("");
      }
    

    {
 dbdata.map(item => {
                    return(
                        <div className="card mb-5" key={item._id} style={{maxWidth:"70%",height:"70%"}} >
                            <img src={item.photo} className="card-img-top" alt="..." style={{maxWidth:"100%",height:"100%"}} />
                            <div className="card-body" >
                                <h6 className="card-text">{item.reviews.length} Reviews
                                <form className="input-group mb-3" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="add a post onChange={handleInput}  value={value} />
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick={(e) => {
                                          makePost(value, item._id)}} type="button">Post</button>
                                    </div>                    
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    )
                })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add a form tag with a onSubmit function, which inside sets the value as an empty string after preventing the default behavior of submitting a form

**Edit: I see you have a makePost function, I think you can move the code of this function inside of my onSubmit one or putting my code inside of your makePost function**

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("");

 const handleInput = e => {
        setValue(e.target.value);
      };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setValue("");
  }

<div className="input-group mb-3">
<form onSubmit={onSubmit}
   <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="add a post" onChange={handleInput} value={value} /></form>
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick={(e) => {makePost(value, item._id)}} type="button">Post</button>
        </div>                    
</div>
```

Comment: it didn't get reset or clear the input after post

Comment: Oh I just saw that the value is not binded to your input, is that normal ? You should have an attribute value with the value in your input tag, like : ```<input value={value} />```

Comment: I think you should copy paste your whole component because some stuff is missing

Comment: No worries, after I added the value={value}, all input has the same values. It is because I am iterating using data.map, so therefore there are many inputs. It is for reviewing products. Thanks

Comment: is your whole component very big ? Copy paste the whole thing if you can, then it will help us to see everything

Comment: But how do I format nicely in the comments box here. It seems I don't have any HTML editor for me to format the code nicely.

Comment: ok, so you need to differentiate all the input values now, maybe you can try to add the index : ```dbdata.map((item, index) => {```, and then pass the index as parameter of your handleInput function ```onChange=(e) => handleInput(e, index)``` and in the function handleInput ```const handleInput = (e, index) => { setValue(state => ({...state, index: e.target.value )}```, then for every input it would be like this ```<input value={value[index]}```

Comment: to handle different inputs values you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63710791/react-hooks-handle-multiple-inputs

Comment: it is not clearing. I am sorry if I missed out on anything here. here is what I have changed.  Sorry, i don't enough space for longer code.
    const handleInput = (e,index) => {
        setValue(state => ({...state, index:e.target.value}));
        };

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            setValue("");
          }
        

dbdata.map((item,index) 

<input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="add a post" onChange={(e) => handleInput(e, index)}  value={value[index]} />

 <form className="input-group mb-3" onSubmit={onSubmit}>