# Not able to clear input after submit and the text parameter return empty

Tags: reactjs

How do I clear the input after button submit and I am not able to get text parameters value from the input after calling the makePost function but I did get the post id though. This is the issue I have posted in the previous post [Clearing Input after submit With react hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65038614/clearing-input-after-submit-with-react-hooks). It is a product review app where users can post reviews. Sorry if have to repost this as a new question because I cannot post the code in the comment section and there is a limit in the number of characters I can post there.

Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciated. Thanks again

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Axios from 'axios'

const Home = () => {
    const [dbdata,setDBData] = useState([])
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");



useEffect(async() => {
        const response = await Axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/posts/allpost', {withCredentials:true})
        setDBData(response.data)
    }, [])
    


const handleInput = (e,index) => {
        setInputValue(state => ({...state, index:e.target.value}));
        };


const onSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            setInputValue("");
          }


const makePost = async(text, id) =>{
        console.log(text + ' ' + id)
        if(text !== "") {
            const response = await Axios.put('http://localhost:5000/api/posts/post',{text:text, postId:id}, {withCredentials:true})
            const postData = dbdata.map(item => {
                if(item._id==response.data._id){
                    return response.data
                }
                else{
                    return item
                }
               
            })
             setDBData(postData)
        }       

    }

 return (
        <div className="p-5 container" style={{marginLeft:"28%"}}>
            {
                dbdata.map((item,index) => {
                    return(
                        <div className="card mb-5" key={item._id} style={{maxWidth:"70%",height:"70%"}} >
                            <img src={item.photo} className="card-img-top" alt="..." style={{maxWidth:"100%",height:"100%"}} />
                            <div className="card-body" >
                               <h6 className="card-text">{item.reviews.length} Reviews
                                <form className="input-group mb-3" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="add a post" onChange={(e) => handleInput(e, index)}  value={inputValue[index]} />
                                    <div className="input-group-append">
                                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={makePost(inputValue, item._id)} type="button">Post</button>
                                    </div>                    
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    )
                })
            }    

        </div>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't mix up methods, for getting the inputs, you are using useState, so kindly go with those conventions,

Check here for a better example
[Sandbox link for inputs example using useState](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-dan-te2x4?file=/src/App.js)