# Why react is repeating my input value in every input

Tags: reactjs

I have a form in react containing 5 feilds. My component is like

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Button } from 'reactstrap';

const ContactAdd = () => {
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [address, setAddress] = useState('');



const changeValue = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
    setEmail(e.target.value);
    setAddress(e.target.value);
};
return (
    <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    <FormGroup>
        <Label>Name</Label>
        <Input
        type='text'
        value={name}
        name='name'
        onChange={changeValue}
        placeholder='Enter Name'
        ></Input>
        <Label>Email</Label>
        <Input
        type='email'
        value={email}
        onChange={changeValue}
        placeholder='Enter Email'
        ></Input>
        <Label>Address</Label>
        <Input
        type='textarea'
        value={address}
        onChange={changeValue}
        placeholder='Enter Address'
        ></Input>
    </FormGroup>
    </Form>
);
};

export default ContactAdd;
```

If i write something in name the email and address is getting same value like if i type v in name then email and address showing v as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hooks: handle multiple inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63710791/react-hooks-handle-multiple-inputs)

Answer (score 0):

your `changeValue` function is used for all the input fields of your form

try something like this:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Button } from 'reactstrap';

const ContactAdd = () => {
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [address, setAddress] = useState('');



const changeValue = (e) => {
    switch(e.target.name) {
       case "name":
          setName(e.target.value);
          break;
       case "email":
          setEmail(e.target.value);
          break;
       case "address":
          setAddress(e.target.value);
          break;
};
return (
    <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    <FormGroup>
        <Label>Name</Label>
        <Input
        type='text'
        value={name}
        name='name'
        onChange={changeValue}
        placeholder='Enter Name'
        ></Input>
        <Label>Email</Label>
        <Input
        type='email'
        name="email"
        value={email}
        onChange={changeValue}
        placeholder='Enter Email'
        ></Input>
        <Label>Address</Label>
        <Input
        type='textarea'
        name="adderess"
        value={address}
        onChange={changeValue}
        placeholder='Enter Address'
        ></Input>
    </FormGroup>
    </Form>
);
};

export default ContactAdd;
```

My personal preference would be this:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Button } from 'reactstrap';

const ContactAdd = () => {
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [address, setAddress] = useState('');


return (
    <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    <FormGroup>
        <Label>Name</Label>
        <Input
        type='text'
        value={name}
        name='name'
        onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)}
        placeholder='Enter Name'
        ></Input>
        <Label>Email</Label>
        <Input
        type='email'
        value={email}
        onChange={(e)=>setEmail(e.target.value)}
        placeholder='Enter Email'
        ></Input>
        <Label>Address</Label>
        <Input
        type='textarea'
        value={address}
        onChange={(e)=>setAddress(e.target.value)}
        placeholder='Enter Address'
        ></Input>
    </FormGroup>
    </Form>
);
};

export default ContactAdd;
```

Comment: I get the point so what should i do to change the value of name,email,address props

Answer (score 0):

You everytime you change a value in any of the fields your same functions are executed. And you can only pass single event as a parameter so when you do `e.target.value` you must do it for 3 diff times.

Try this :

```
<Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
<FormGroup>
    <Label>Name</Label>
    <Input
    type='text'
    value={name}
    name='name'
    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value) }
    placeholder='Enter Name'
    ></Input>
    <Label>Email</Label>
    <Input
    type='email'
    value={email}
    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value) }
    placeholder='Enter Email'
    ></Input>
    <Label>Address</Label>
    <Input
    type='textarea'
    value={address}
    onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value) }
    placeholder='Enter Address'
    ></Input>
</FormGroup>
</Form>
```

Comment: with this you won't need theChangeValue function