# Maintaining multiple user inputs to antd Select in a single useState variable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I want to store the information of multiple inputs entered into [antd Select](https://ant.design/components/select) components in a single state variable but am having trouble getting the below to work.

This example is solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63710791/react-hooks-handle-multiple-inputs) for a form but the same solution doesn't seem to work for antd Select component. There are two inputs: a first name and a last name that I want to remember. The below code doesn't work because e doesn't have an attribute called name is what the console tells me. I also tried e.target.name and e.target.value but I get an error that e doesn't have an attribute called a target either. What is the right way to do this?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Select } from 'antd';

const App = () =>{

  const [varState, setVarState] = useState({firstName:'Jack', lastName:'Smith'});
  const firstNameOptions = [ {label:'Jack', value:'Jack'}, {label:'Jill',value:'Jill'}, {label:'Bill',value:'Bill'} ];
  const lastNameOptions = [ {label:'Smith', value:'Smith'}, {label:'Potter',value:'Potter'}, {label:'Bach',value:'Bach'} ];

  const changeState = (e) => {
    setVarState( prevState => ({ ...prevState, [e.name]: e.value}));
    console.log(varState)
  };

  return ( <>
      <div>
        <Select name={'firstName'} defaultValue={'Pick One'} options={firstNameOptions} onChange={changeState}   />
        <Select name={'lastName'} defaultValue={'Pick One'} options={lastNameOptions} onChange={changeState}   />
      </div>
      </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

1. At the heart of it, it seems that I don't know how to name the Select components in such a way that their names can be passed on to the onChange handler.
2. More generally, given a component like antd Select, how can I figure out what the right "name field" is for this component so that it's value can be passed on to an onChange handler? For instance, what in the [documentation](https://ant.design/components/select) for select gives this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Select component seems to be sending the value instead of the events object. So, You can just make a closure and pass the name of the select. Also, for consoling you can make use of a useEffect which only consoles when the state has been updated. Otherwise, you could see previous state as state updates are asynchronous. Below is a working solution.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Select } from "antd";

const App = () => {
  const [varState, setVarState] = useState({
    firstName: "Jack",
    lastName: "Smith"
  });
  const firstNameOptions = [
    { label: "Jack", value: "Jack" },
    { label: "Jill", value: "Jill" },
    { label: "Bill", value: "Bill" }
  ];
  const lastNameOptions = [
    { label: "Smith", value: "Smith" },
    { label: "Potter", value: "Potter" },
    { label: "Bach", value: "Bach" }
  ];

  // for consoling when the state updates
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(varState);
  }, [varState.firstName, varState.lastName]);

  const changeState = (value, identifier) => {
    // console.log(value, identifier);
    setVarState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [identifier]: value }));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Select
          name={"firstName"}
          defaultValue={"Pick One"}
          options={firstNameOptions}
          onChange={(val) => changeState(val, "firstName")}
        />
        <Select
          name={"lastName"}
          defaultValue={"Pick One"}
          options={lastNameOptions}
          onChange={(val) => changeState(val, "lastName")}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Quick question: If I put a console.log(varState) right after the setVarState call, the printed value is one step behind the selection I see in the UI. Do you know why this is? Shouldn't my setVarState call already have changed the varState? It's the same issue that the other answer has.

Comment: That's because setState is a asynchronous function. so the update happens asynchronously and so there is a delay. using the useEffect we are guaranteeing the consoling is only happening when a state update happens

Answer (score 1):

yes, Actually antd doesn't have attribute `name` for input fields. antdesign directly gives the selected value, we need to do some tweeks to achieve this.

Here is the solution:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Select } from 'antd';

const firstNameOptions = [ {label:'Jack', value:'Jack'}, {label:'Jill',value:'Jill'}, {label:'Bill',value:'Bill'} ];
const lastNameOptions = [ {label:'Smith', value:'Smith'}, {label:'Potter',value:'Potter'}, {label:'Bach',value:'Bach'} ];

const App = () =>{

  const [varState, setVarState] = useState(null);
      
  const changeState = (fieldName) => (value) => {
    setVarState( prevState => ({ ...prevState, [fieldName]: value}));
    console.log(varState)
  };

  return ( <>
      <div>
        <Select defaultValue={'Pick One'} options={firstNameOptions} onChange={changeState('firstName')}   />
        <Select defaultValue={'Pick One'} options={lastNameOptions} onChange={changeState('lastName')}   />
      </div>
      </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I hope this helps

Comment: So you are basically making changeState to be a function that returns a function. if you pass in "firstName" it returns  a firstName modifying function and ditto for "lastName". One issue I notice though is that this approach seems to keep the firstName and lastName one step behind the selected values in the UI. Can you explain why?